# How to use custom code generators in waf build system?

Tags: c++, code-generation, waf

I have a program that generates files that are included in .cpp files.

I want waf to build generator, find out what files need to be generated, generate them and compile everything else.

```
cxx gen.cpp -> gen
gen 1.in -> 1.out
gen 2.in -> 2.out
cxx program.cpp -> program
```

(program.cpp includes 1.out and 2.out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/waf-users/E7sh_AB5kcc
Example in the waf book: http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html#_project_organization

Comment: Link answers are strongly discouraged.

Comment: Indeed, the link is now dead. Replaced with https://waf.io/book/#_project_organization